# Pass login information from Apache/PHP to Tomcat/GWT

Tags: php, security, gwt

We are planning to deploy our GWT module as explained in
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideRPCDeployment
under the section "Using Tomcat with Apache HTTPD and a proxy"

Basically, we configured Apache/PHP server to pass on the requests to a Tomcat/GWT server that match a part of the URL. That worked as expected.
Now we would like to pass the information of the currently logged in user from Apache/PHP to the GWT module.

My initial idea was to load the GWT module from a PHP page (by including it's nocache.js) and include a login token with it which the GWT module can read. 
But I am not sure if it is safe to read a DOM value and consider that as a login token.

Any suggestions for what would be the best way to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO it is definitifly the best idea to use a login-token, that is passed from apache/php to your gwt project. To pass this token, you have three possibilities:

**First one:** You can pass your token using a cookie. Write your token into a cookie and read it again in your GWT-context:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies;
Collection<String> cookies = Cookies.getCookieNames();
```

An example on dealing with cookies from GWT you can find in the [GWT-Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCookies).

**Second one:** Instead of writing your token to a cookie, you can pass it with a HTTP GET and read this again within your GWT-context:

```
// returns whole query string 
public static String getQueryString() {
    return Window.Location.getQueryString();
}

// returns specific parameter
public static String getQueryString(String name) {   
    return Window.Location.getParameter(name);
}
```

*This method is -IMHO- that one you should never ever choose!*

**Third one:** Instead of a HTTP GET you can also use a HTTP POST. The HTTP POST is send to the server. So you have to handle the request on your server-side with a simple servlet. This can be implemented as singelton and so be readable from your GWT-server-context. This method is a bit complex and brings a lot of work, since you then have to pass your information back to the GWT-client-context.

Which version is the best for you, depends on the details of your project. Usually I would say, that the Cookie-Version is the best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using a hidden input value on the PHP page for now to insert a random token and save the user's Id with the token back in the database. The GWT module will read and delete that upon loading.